# python3 urllib.request.urlopen timeout error

Tags: urllib2, urllib, python-3.3

i have script witch gets data from site. First i wrote it in 2.7 python and its works.
When i rewrite it to python3 i have problem.
In python2.7 that works fine

```
     for x in xrange(len(ll.string2)-1):
            psR = urllib2.urlopen(ll.string2[x]).read()
            nrL = Przystanek()  
            nrL.feed(psR)
            self.BusExtData += nrL.string2
```

python3

```
        for x in range(len(ll.string2)-1):
             psR = urllib.request.urlopen(ll.string2[x],timeout=3000).read().decode('iso-8859-2')
             nrL = Przystanek() 
             nrL.feed(psR)
             self.BusExtData += nrL.string2
```

Upper code generate timeout error.

```
 i = 0      
 while i<(len(ll.string2)-1):           
 try:
                psR = urllib.request.urlopen(ll.string2[i],timeout=3000).read().decode('iso-8859-2')
                nrL = Przystanek()
                nrL.feed(psR)
                self.BusExtData += nrL.string2
                i=i+1           
except:
                print("Error")
                i=i-1

                pass
```

I avoid this problem with upper case. But i dont know why urllib2.urlopen dont make timeout error. When i use urllib.request.urlopen i get this error message:

> urllib.error.URLError:urlopen error timed out

or

> urllib.error.URLError:urlopen error timed out [WinError 10060]

What is difference between urlib2.urlopen and urllib.request.urlopen?

Comment: did you ever get a resolution to this? Also how did you use upper case to resolve it?